# Apexcharts - running in jsfiddle - but not an my PC

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I want to update a chart.
https://jsfiddle.net/q2hLgk9z/2/
the original idea comes from here:https://jsfiddle.net/wxzpk9dn/2/

```
<head>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.18.1/dist/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div>
      <input type="radio" id="columnGraph" name="graph" value="line" />
      <label for="columnGraph">Line</label>
</div>
<div>
      <input type="radio" id="barGraph" name="graph" value="line1" checked />
      <label for="barGraph">Barra</label>
</div>

<div id="chartwind" ></div> </pre>
```

and script

```
  <script>
      // CHART OPTIONS by chart type
      let chartOptions = {
        line1: {
          chart: { type: "line" },
          series: [
            { name: "One", type: "line", data: [15, 20] },
            { name: "Two", type: "line", data: [30, 25] },
          ],
          labels: ["2017", "2018"],
          stroke: { width: 2 },
        },
        line: {
          chart: { type: "line" },
          series: [
            { name: "2017", type: "line", data: [65, 20] },
            { name: "2018", type: "line", data: [15, 25] },
          ],
          labels: ["from", "to"],
          stroke: { width: 5 },
        },
      };
    //select the radiobuttons
   var chartTypeControlButtons = document.querySelectorAll(
       'input[type=radio][name="graphicType"]'
    ),
      chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked = document.querySelectorAll(
        'input[type=radio][name="graphicType"]:checked'
    );
   // Chart type changing (HANDLER)
   //switch between the graphs
      function changeHandler(event) {
        let selectedChartType = this.value,
          updatedChartOptions = chartOptions[selectedChartType];
        chart.updateOptions(updatedChartOptions);
      }
      //Listener for the radios
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartTypeControlButtons, function (radio) {
        radio.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
      });
      // Render the chart with initial options and then
      let initialChartType = chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked[0].value,
        // think of it as a preparing the ground
        // USE 'bar' as the type. If you choose 'pie' ... you will get glithes
        initialChartOptions = {
          chart: {
            width: 350,
            type: "line",
          },
          series: [],
        };

      // Create chart with init options
      // Note that the link to the chart object is in the GLOBAL scope
      var chart = new ApexCharts(
        document.getElementById("chartwind"),
        initialChartOptions
      );
      chart.render(); // Firstly, prepare the ground
      chart.updateOptions(chartOptions[initialChartType]); // Secondly, draw we want
    </script>

    <div id="chartwind"></div>
  </body>
```

In Jsfiddle it is working but not an my PC.
I load the apexchartversion as fiddle (3.18.1) - but this does not matter.^It is the same issue with the latest version.

I get 2 errormessages:
in the start: after chart.render:Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element not found (maybe because series ist []. But it does not change with values.
then in the update mode: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Do you have an idea, what I can try on my machine? (I have the same issue on different browsers).
Maybe you have an idea about the difference to fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Just define your script file path after your `<div id="chartwind"></div>`.
It will work.

Example:

**index.html**

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.18.1/dist/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div>
      <input type="radio" id="columnGraph" name="graph" value="line" />
      <label for="columnGraph">Line</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="barGraph" name="graph" value="line1" checked />
      <label for="barGraph">Barra</label>
    </div>

<div id="chartwind" ></div>
<script src="./apex.js"></script>
```

**apex.js**

```
let chartOptions = {
  line1: {
    chart: {
      type: "line"
    },
    series: [{
        name: "One",
        type: "line",
        data: [15, 20]
      },
      {
        name: "Two",
        type: "line",
        data: [30, 25]
      },
    ],
    labels: ["2017", "2018"],
    stroke: {
      width: 2
    },
  },
  line: {
    chart: {
      type: "line"
    },
    series: [{
        name: "2017",
        type: "line",
        data: [65, 20]
      },
      {
        name: "2018",
        type: "line",
        data: [15, 25]
      },
    ],
    labels: ["from", "to"],
    stroke: {
      width: 5
    },
  },
};

var chartTypeControlButtons = document.querySelectorAll(
    'input[type=radio][name="graph"]'
  ),
  chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked = document.querySelectorAll(
    'input[type=radio][name="graph"]:checked'
  );
//console.log("checked", chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked.length);
//console.log("radios", chartTypeControlButtons.length);

function changeHandler(event) {
  let selectedChartType = this.value,
    updatedChartOptions = chartOptions[selectedChartType];
  //console.log("change");
  chart.updateOptions(updatedChartOptions);
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartTypeControlButtons, function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
});
// Render the chart with initial options and then
// you can update it with ANY wished options
//  let initialChartType = $(chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked).val(),
//console.log("text", chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked[0].value);
let initialChartType = chartTypeControlButtonInitChecked[0].value,
  // think of it as a preparing the ground
  // USE 'bar' as the type. If you choose 'pie' ... you will get glithes
  initialChartOptions = {
    chart: {
      width: 350,
      type: "line",
    },

    labels: ["from", "to"],
    stroke: {
      width: 2
    },
    series: [],
  };

// Create chart with init options
// Note that the link to the chart object is in the GLOBAL scope
var chart = new ApexCharts(
  document.getElementById("chartwind"),
  initialChartOptions
);
//console.log("initialChartType", initialChartType);
chart.render(); // Firstly, prepare the ground
//console.log(chartOptions[initialChartType]);
chart.updateOptions(chartOptions[initialChartType]); // Secondly, draw we want
// chart.updateOptions(newOptions); Redraw we want
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - it was too simple :-)